# Java to match name of tag multiple times in XML

Tags: java, xml, dom

There are XML files, which contain a specified tag, which is `tagName` variable in code. This tag has one or more occurrences in each file. I use following code to get the value, but it matches just the first occurrence of the tag.

```
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = null;
DocumentBuilder docBuild = null;
String st="";

try {
    dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    docBuild = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = docBuild.parse(new File(myfolder + "/report.xml"));
    NodeList children = doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(0).getChildNodes();
    Element child = (Element)children.item(1);
    st=child.getTextContent();
    st = st.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    System.out.println(st);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `doc.getElementsByTagName("tagName");`  returns a list of elements of specified name. You are limiting it to the first occurance by calling `item(0)` on that list. Remove that and iterate over the list to process all matching elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++){
  NodeList children = nodes.item(i).getChildNodes();
  Element child = (Element)children.item(1);
  st=child.getTextContent();
  st = st.replaceAll("\\s+","");
  System.out.println(st);
}
```